# "Many" quantifier in first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

Suppose I want to express this sentence in first-order logic:

```
"Many printers are broken"
```

If $p(x)$ is true if the term $x$ is a printer and $b(x)$ is true if $x$ is broken, how can I express this sentence?

Comment: You cannot; you can see [Generalized quantifiers](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/generalized-quantifiers/#arbi) :  see e.g. $\text {most}_M (A,B)$ ("most $A$ are $B$").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First-order logic does not have a notion of "many" - this, like "most," "almost all," etc. is an example of a [generalized quantifier](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/generalized-quantifiers/), and handling them takes us to *extensions* of first-order logic.

We *can* express each of the following in first-order logic:

- "Some printer is broken." ($\exists x(p(x)\wedge b(x))$)
- "Multiple printers are broken." ($\exists x,y(x\not=y \wedge p(x)\wedge p(y)\wedge b(x)\wedge b(y))$)
- "At least $n$ printers are broken." ($\exists x_1,...,x_n((\bigwedge_{1\le i<j\le n}x_i\not=x_j)\wedge (\bigwedge_{1\le k\le n}p(x_k)\wedge b(x_k))$)
- "All printers are broken." ($\forall x(p(x)\implies b(x))$)

Comment: Is the inequality between terms an extension of first order logic ?

Comment: @Koinos You mean "$\not=$?" No - "$=$" is a logical symbol in first-order logic *(this is actually historically contingent - early versions of first-order logic didn't always include $=$)*, and "$a\not=b$" is understood as an abbreviation for "$\neg(a=b)$ (similarly, "$\exists x,y$" is an abbreviation for "$\exists x\exists y$," and etc.).